# Adjusting Plotly graph objects to cleanup my wafer map

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

Okay, I am trying to build out a heat map that looks at etch depth on Si wafer. I have successfully generated the graph and have been playing with several of the 'options' but visually it still looks like trash.

[Wafer Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFpaR.png)

A few questions:

1. How to make the data squares **actual squares** or possibly even another shape (like a filled circle).
2. I have data that drives up and down both axes (28-30 points total) that are very, very, thin rectangles. How can I turn these guys into squares as well?
3. Last item. I know by using 'xgap' and 'ygap' I can help some of the dead areas by overlap. Is there a better/simpler way to do this? You lose a little bit of data with the overlap.

Here is the code for reference:

```
import csv
import plotly.graph_objects as go
  
# Open the CSV file
with open('MyCSV.csv', 'r') as f:
  # Read the CSV file using a dict reader
  reader = csv.DictReader(f)
  
  # Extract the x, y, and third columns
  coords = [(float(row['X(mm)']), float(row['Y(mm)']), float(row['Delta Thick (nm)'])) for row in reader]

# Extract the x and y coordinates and the third column values
x, y, z = zip(*coords)

# Create the heatmap
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
                   x=x,
                   y=y,
                   z=z, 
                   xgap=30,
                   ygap=30,
                   colorscale=[[0, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'], [0.5, 'rgb(255, 255, 0)'], [1, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)']]))

# Set the aspect ratio of the x and y axes
fig.update_layout(
    width=800, 
    height=800
)

# Set the limits of the x and y axes
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(range=[-80, 80]), yaxis=dict(range=[-80, 80]))

# Add a circle to the heat map
fig.add_shape(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0=-75,
    y0=-75,
    x1=75,
    y1=75,
    fillcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    line_color='black',
    line_width=2)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Thanks all!

I've tried adjusting xgap and ygap, tried changing position of the squares, and have tried using an entirely different heatmap config to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide data that can reproduce the graphs in the question?

Comment: @r-beginners for security reasons I won’t give the exact data but here is a way of generating it: a list of 225 equally spaced coordinate pairs with an additional random number between 150 and 250. So each element in the list looks like “(x0,y0,z0), (x1,y1,z1),…(x225,y225,z225)”. Hope this helps!